# Error reading built in keras datasets - Type Error: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I've just installed the `keras` and `tensorflow` packages. I'm looking to get started with building some deep learning models, but I'm immediately stuck trying to read example data into the `R` environment.

Consider the following code:

```
#loading keras library
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

#loading the keras inbuilt cifar10 dataset
?dataset_cifar10 #to see the help file for details of dataset
cifar <- dataset_cifar10()
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras\datasets\mnist.py", line 17, in load_data
    file_hash='8a61469f7ea1b51cbae51d4f78837e45')
  File "C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 220, in get_file
    urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 274, in urlretrieve
    reporthook(blocknum, bs, size)
  File "C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 213, in dl_progress
    ProgressTracker.progbar = Progbar(total_size)
  File "C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 270, in __init__
    self._dynamic_display = (sys.stdout.isatty() or
```

Any ideas on what's going on here? The suggestion of installing the reticulate package from git hub versus `CRAN` is suggested [here](https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/33) , but this doesn't solve my issue. Any ideas?

My session info as it relates to `keras` and `tensorflow` is here:

```
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/stc004/AppData/Local/CONTIN~1/ANACON~1/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1
version:        3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.11.3
keras:          C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras

python versions found: 
 C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
 C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\\python.exe
> tf_config()
TensorFlow v1.2.1 (C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\keras)
Python v3.6 (C:\Users\stc004\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\python.exe)
```

Answer (score 2):

In RStudio-1.1.383 I can replicate the problem. The issue vanished when I cloned the Github source for keras and installed in Python (according to the [documentation](https://keras.io/)).

Another idea is to use RStudio-1.0.153 where the problem should not occur (nevertheless you need to follow the suggestion from the git hub you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

Changing Keras version to 2.0.0 helped me with similar problem.

```
pip install keras==2.0.0
```

I was using 2.0.9 before.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in response. The issue was solved here:
https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues/180